# Creating a tutorial on a form or report

Tags: forms, report

I want to create a tutorial inside a form showing how to use my database. I created it in PowerPoint and saved it as a PDF. I was wondering if it was possible to attach this PDF in my form. I also saved these slides as images on my computer, tried to attached them to a form and it exceeded 22 inches in lenght. is there any way around this any suggestions perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript and other tools to show the pdf as a slideshow, I recommend that you use this tool its free and you can integrate your slides in a very easy way with javascript.

http://ajaxslideshow.com/show-pdf-slideshow-javascript.html

Comment: Looks very interesting I will give it a shot but how will i add that to access. Any tips?

Comment: What do you mean by adding it to access?? can you be more specific?

Comment: How do i make Access open this

Comment: I still dont know what you mean by access... do you want to open it with an application? If you have the images you could use JQuery instead there are various slideshow plugins.

Comment: Ok, in my form I have a  help button. A user will click this button when to see the help presentation i created. Can i add this slide show form vislual slideshow in access or will i have to set this button as link to a web page in my server

Comment: Hehe I understand you know! You can add it in access in real time without redirecting to another link. For that I recommend JQuery plugin SlideJS http://www.slidesjs.com/ you can play and stop a slideshow like slideshare, you can view the examples in the link.